# Zend Framework - storing and retrieving cookies

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies

I try to put the user's email in a cookie when he logs in, and retrieve it at his next visit.
The code below doesn't work, obviously I am missing something.

When user submits login info,  store the email in cookie:
$cookie = new Zend_Http_Cookie('emailLogin', urlencode($email), 'localhost');

At the next user's visit, retrieve the user's email: 
$email = $this->_request->getCookie('emailLogin');

(I had already a debate in #zftalk on why I need to store the email in cookie, I don't want to discuss that again please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what Zend_Http_Cookie is for, see [php setcookie vs Zend_Http_Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883658/php-setcookie-vs-zend-http-cookie). Try just using the native PHP setcookie method, or sessions.