# php setcookie vs Zend_Http_Cookie

Tags: php, zend-framework

Why this code not working, and how can I make it works like

`setcookie('cookie_name','cookie_value');`

**The code that not create cookie**:

```
$cookie=new Zend_Http_Cookie('cookie_name','cookie_value','.google.com');
```

Or what difference between:

```
setcookie('cookie_name','cookie_value');
```

vs

```
$cookie=new Zend_Http_Cookie('cookie_name','cookie_value','.google.com');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Zend_Http_Cookie is not for setting cookies, it is a companion class for Zend_Http_Client. Let's say you wanted to screen scape some content off a site but that content is only available if you are logged in. You could use Zend_Http_Client to post your credentials to the login form, the server would then send back a session cookie. You could then include this session cookie in a subsequent request to the page you want to scrape in order to simulate a logged in user viewing that page.

To set cookies in ZF you can just use the native PHP function, or possibly store the data in the session instead.